# MySQL duplicate entry error even though it is not a duplicate entry

Tags: php, mysql

I have a strange error when I tried to add few specific data to the table. Following is my MySQL command.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `phonenumbers` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=30 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `phonenumberverifier`.`phonenumbers` (`id`, `number`, `added`) VALUES (NULL, '3522316712', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

"id" is the primary key and added field is current time stamp.

Following is the error I get.

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'number'
```

Please note that the number value 2147483647 exists as a record. But it has nothing to do with this new entry. This table doesn't have any dependency with other tables.

Please let me know what has caused this issue and what needs to be done to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If `id` is the primary key as you stated, why is that not reflected in your `CREATE` statement?

Comment: Plainly, there is no PK here

Comment: Also, as hellcode pointed out, your primary key should probably be unsigned if your application allows for non-negative keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is particularly strange, because your snippet of code does not specify that `number` is unique (and you show no unique index on it).  I will assume this is an oversight, because the error message is pretty clear on this point.

What is happening is that you are assigning a larger value than allowed into the field.  As explained in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html):

> When MySQL stores a value in a numeric column that is outside the
>   permissible range of the column data type, the result depends on the
>   SQL mode in effect at the time:
>
> - If strict SQL mode is enabled, MySQL rejects the out-of-range value with an error, and the insert fails, in accordance with the SQL
>     standard.
> - If no restrictive modes are enabled, MySQL clips the value to the appropriate endpoint of the range and stores the resulting value
>     instead.
>
> When an out-of-range value is assigned to an integer column, MySQL
>   stores the value representing the corresponding endpoint of the column
>   data type range. If you store 256 into a TINYINT or TINYINT UNSIGNED
>   column, MySQL stores 127 or 255, respectively.

So, your number gets assigned the largest possible value.  If you do this more than once *and* there is a unique constraint/index, then you will get the error that you see.

If you have no unique constraint/index, then the value `2147483647` would be placed in the column each time the inserted value is too large.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the data type to BIGINT.

Answer (score 1):

number is defined as integer value and 2147483647 is the maximum value a signed integer can take (minimum -2147483648). I guess in your create statement is the fact missing that number is defined as unique key. You should have a look at your actual table definition. The one you provided here could not be reason. Then number would just be 2147483647 after insertion with no error message.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the data type to BIGINT.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, unsigned INT may be only from -2147483648 to -2147483647 (according to [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html)). So, it just can't be 3522316712.

Comment: No no, int is always int. It is 4 bytes in size.

Comment: _Unsigned_ INT are from 0 to 4294967295. The range you state is for _signed_ INT.